Spectral Theory: A Key to Unlocking Efficient Insights in Network Datasets
In the context of directed or undirected graphs, matrices such as adjacency and Laplacian matrices are commonly used. The eigenbasis of these matrices addresses some practical implications, such as centrality measures (like PageRank), and it is also crucial for clustering (community detection).
In the realm of graph signal processing, What practical implications have been identified in the literature by analyzing the eigenbasis?

"in the literature": that's too broad. Obviously, once you do research, you start by looking into basically anything that you can do with the properties of your research subject, so there's going to be literature on almost anything that remotely makes sense. I think you are really looking for a discussion forum there, not a question and answer platform like this one…
